# How to call parent component method from child lwc component?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I need one sample code for calling parent LWC component method from child LWC component?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] then [edit] your question to show what you tried and where you are stuck. We help with specific challenges rather than provide a free coding service. Without changes your question is likely to be closed without answer.

Answer (score 3):

the standard pattern for this kind of interaction between components is to have the child component fire events for the parent component to react to.

If you're looking for details of how this works, including sample code and best practices, you should read through the [Communicate with Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events) section of the Lightning Web Components Dev Guide.